# Remove dictionary from list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

If I have a list of dictionaries, say:

```
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'paul'},
 {'id': 2, 'name': 'john'}]
```

and I would like to remove the dictionary with `id` of 2 (or name `'john'`), what is the most efficient way to go about this programmatically (that is to say, I don't know the index of the entry in the list so it can't simply be popped).

Answer (score 154, accepted):

```
thelist[:] = [d for d in thelist if d.get('id') != 2]
```

**Edit**: as some doubts have been expressed in a comment about the performance of this code (some based on misunderstanding Python's performance characteristics, some on assuming beyond the given specs that there is exactly one dict in the list with a value of 2 for key 'id'), I wish to offer reassurance on this point.

On an old Linux box, measuring this code:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s"lod=[{'id':i, 'name':'nam%s'%i} for i in range(99)]; import random" "thelist=list(lod); random.shuffle(thelist); thelist[:] = [d for d in thelist if d.get('id') != 2]"
10000 loops, best of 3: 82.3 usec per loop
```

of which about 57 microseconds for the random.shuffle (needed to ensure that the element to remove is not ALWAYS at the same spot;-) and 0.65 microseconds for the initial copy (whoever worries about performance impact of shallow copies of Python lists is most obviously out to lunch;-), needed to avoid altering the original list in the loop (so each leg of the loop does have something to delete;-).

When it is known that there is exactly one item to remove, it's possible to locate and remove it even more expeditiously:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s"lod=[{'id':i, 'name':'nam%s'%i} for i in range(99)]; import random" "thelist=list(lod); random.shuffle(thelist); where=(i for i,d in enumerate(thelist) if d.get('id')==2).next(); del thelist[where]"
10000 loops, best of 3: 72.8 usec per loop
```

(use the `next` builtin rather than the `.next` method if you're on Python 2.6 or better, of course) -- but this code breaks down if the number of dicts that satisfy the removal condition is not exactly one. Generalizing this, we have:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s"lod=[{'id':i, 'name':'nam%s'%i} for i in range(33)]*3; import random" "thelist=list(lod); where=[i for i,d in enumerate(thelist) if d.get('id')==2]; where.reverse()" "for i in where: del thelist[i]"
10000 loops, best of 3: 23.7 usec per loop
```

where the shuffling can be removed because there are already three equispaced dicts to remove, as we know. And the listcomp, unchanged, fares well:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s"lod=[{'id':i, 'name':'nam%s'%i} for i in range(33)]*3; import random" "thelist=list(lod); thelist[:] = [d for d in thelist if d.get('id') != 2]"
10000 loops, best of 3: 23.8 usec per loop
```

totally neck and neck, with even just 3 elements of 99 to be removed. With longer lists and more repetitions, this holds even more of course:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s"lod=[{'id':i, 'name':'nam%s'%i} for i in range(33)]*133; import random" "thelist=list(lod); where=[i for i,d in enumerate(thelist) if d.get('id')==2]; where.reverse()" "for i in where: del thelist[i]"
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.11 msec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s"lod=[{'id':i, 'name':'nam%s'%i} for i in range(33)]*133; import random" "thelist=list(lod); thelist[:] = [d for d in thelist if d.get('id') != 2]"
1000 loops, best of 3: 998 usec per loop
```

All in all, it's obviously not worth deploying the subtlety of making and reversing the list of indices to remove, vs the perfectly simple and obvious list comprehension, to possibly gain 100 nanoseconds in one small case -- and lose 113 microseconds in a larger one;-). Avoiding or criticizing simple, straightforward, and perfectly performance-adequate solutions (like list comprehensions for this general class of "remove some items from a list" problems) is a particularly nasty example of Knuth's and Hoare's well-known thesis that "premature optimization is the root of all evil in programming"!-)

Comment: Two reasons why this is bad: it copies the entire list, and it traverses the entire list even if the dictionary containing id 2 is the very first element.

Comment: @imagist, it's nevertheless fastest -- MEASURE it, for goodness sake, don't just ASSUME you know what you're talking about, esp. when you obviously don't;-), *ESPECIALLY* when the item to remove is the first (it avoids moving every other item). And there's no indication in the original question that every dict in the list MUST always have a different value corresponding to 'id'.

Comment: Hmmmm. Not bad. There are two approaches: make a new list with some elements filtered out or modify the existing list to remove some elements. This is just the former approach. And as far as that goes, there is nothing to say that a dictionary with id=2 won't appear more than once in the list. It's a list -- there is no guarantee of uniqueness. And the OP did not suggest this limitation.

Comment: @Alex, exactly - I love list comprehensions for their sheer blinding speed. And, since as of Python 3 `filter` will return an iterator, this should be standard practice.

Comment: @hughdbrown and @Meredith, I've now added copious measurements and variants showing performance behavior in various cases -- hope it's as interesting to read as it was to code and measure;-)

Comment: What is the colon for in `theList[:]`?

Comment: @kzh: `theList[:]` is equivalent to `theList[0:len(theList)]`.  In this context, it means "change theList in-place".

Comment: What is the difference between `theList[:] = ..` and `theList = ..`?

Comment: A very clever response! never thought of doing something like this but have run into the problem before. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to write an exception, that if a user inputs for what equals !=, and it isnt found, to print a message? For example, if a user wrote thelist[:] = [d for d in thelist if d.get('id') != 4` and of course this doesn't exist, how would one make a message be printed to the user that no id in a dictionary has this value?

Answer (score 12):

Here's a way to do it with a list comprehension (assuming you name your list 'foo'):

```
[x for x in foo if not (2 == x.get('id'))]
```

Substitute `'john' == x.get('name')` or whatever as appropriate.

`filter` also works:

`foo.filter(lambda x: x.get('id')!=2, foo)`

And if you want a generator you can use itertools:

`itertools.ifilter(lambda x: x.get('id')!=2, foo)`

However, as of Python 3, `filter` will return an iterator anyway, so the list comprehension is really the best choice, as Alex suggested.

Comment: also, .get is better than [] here, as it doesn't break if some dict in the list does NOT have an entry for key 'id'.

Answer (score 10):

```
# assume ls contains your list
for i in range(len(ls)):
    if ls[i]['id'] == 2:
        del ls[i]
        break
```

Will probably be faster than the list comprehension methods on average because it doesn't traverse the whole list if it finds the item in question early on.

Comment: will raise `KeyError` if dict has no `id`. and that's not what OP asked for.

Comment: @Imagist +1 This was exactly what I was looking for. Note to @SilentGhost: You could just use a different key, other than `id`, if you wanted to target another value, ie: `if ls[i]['name'] == 'john':` would match and remove that dictionary.

Answer (score 8):

This is not properly an anwser (as I think you already have some quite good of them), but... have you considered of having a dictionary of `<id>:<name>` instead of a list of dictionaries?

Comment: +1: "If it's hard, you're doing it wrong."  If you want to remove things by an attribute, use a dictionary, keyed by the attribute.  Much simpler.

Comment: ...as long as you don't care at all about preserving the order of items, never want to remove things by a different attribute, are happy with never allowing any duplicates regarding that one attribute, etc, etc -- far too many restrictions above and beyond any specs expressed by the OP, to make this suggestion reasonable;-).

Comment: If I'd had to take all those specs for granted, I would have said "use a database" xD

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
a = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'paul'},
     {'id': 2, 'name': 'john'}]

for e in range(len(a) - 1, -1, -1):
    if a[e]['id'] == 2:
        a.pop(e)
```

If You can't pop from the beginning - pop from the end, it won't ruin the for loop.

Comment: You mean "range(len(a) - 1, -1, -1)", not "range(len(a) - 1, 0, -1)". This does not include the first element of the list. I've heard word that reversed() is preferred nowadays. See my code below.

Comment: Here's what I was getting at:

>>> a = list(range(5))
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> range(len(a) - 1, -1, -1)
[4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
>>> range(len(a) - 1, 0, -1)
[4, 3, 2, 1]

Just wait for the comment-mangling...

Answer (score 1):

Supposed your python version is 3.6 or greater, and that you don't need the deleted item this would be less expensive...

If the dictionaries in the list are unique :

```
for i in range(len(dicts)):
    if dicts[i].get('id') == 2:
        del dicts[i]
        break
```

If you want to remove all matched items :

```
for i in range(len(dicts)):
    if dicts[i].get('id') == 2:
        del dicts[i]
```

You can also to this to be sure getting id key won't raise keyerror regardless the python version

> if dicts[i].get('id', None) == 2

Comment: The code to remove all matched items won't work. Deleting from the list will cause the index to change, which will cause this code to skip an item.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something along the following lines:

```
def destructively_remove_if(predicate, list):
      for k in xrange(len(list)):
          if predicate(list[k]):
              del list[k]
              break
      return list

  list = [
      { 'id': 1, 'name': 'John' },
      { 'id': 2, 'name': 'Karl' },
      { 'id': 3, 'name': 'Desdemona' } 
  ]

  print "Before:", list
  destructively_remove_if(lambda p: p["id"] == 2, list)
  print "After:", list
```

Unless you build something akin to an index over your data, I
don't think that you can do better than doing a brute-force "table
scan" over the entire list. If your data is sorted by the key you
are using, you might be able to employ the *bisect* module to
find the object you are looking for somewhat faster.

Comment: what is xrange ? @Dirk

Comment: `xrange` is/was in Python 2, what's nowadays called `range` in Python 3. The example as written is still Python 2 code (look at the date, observe the use of `print` as statement instead of as function).

Answer (score 0):

From the update on [pep448](https://peps.python.org/pep-0448/) on unpacking generalisations (python 3.5 and onwards) while iterating a list of dicts with a temporary variable, let's say row, You can take the dict of the current iteration in, using **row, merge new keys in or use a boolean operation to filter out dict(s) from your list of dicts.

Keep in mind **row will output a new dictionary.

For example your starting list of dicts :

```
data = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'paul'},{'id': 2, 'name': 'john'}]
```

if we want to filter out id 2 :

```
data = [{**row} for row in data if row['id']!=2]
```

if you want to filter out John :

```
data = [{**row} for row in data if row['name']!='John']
```

not directly related to the question but if you want to a add new key :

```
data = [{**row, 'id_name':str(row['id'])+'_'+row['name']} for row in data]
```

It's also a tiny bit faster than the accepted solution.

Comment: it should be `if row['id']!=2`

Answer (score -1):

**Try this:**
example remove 'joh' for the list

```
for id,elements in enumerate(dictionary):
    if elements['name']=='john':
        del dictionary[id]
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not just delete the items starting from the end of the list? That way the index is constant for the rest of the items as you're going through the loop.

In this example, notice there are 2 of the same id of 0:

```py
myList = [{'id': 0, 'name': 'paul'},
          {'id': 2, 'name': 'john'}
          {'id': 0, 'name': 'raul'},
          {'id': 4, 'name': 'oscar'}]

for item in myList[::-1]:
            
    if item['id'] == 0:             
        myList.remove(item)
```

Utilizing the `remove()` method, you can delete the unwanted items effectively when you don't have the index.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! [zeroDivision's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1235647/1519716) from 14 years ago already mentions looping backwards to avoid problems modifying while iterating. Invoking `list.remove` will start its own search, which is pointless when the item to be removed has already been located.