# Delete the dictionary in the list which value is to low

Tags: python, python-3.x

can someone repair my code because it ends after it deletes the first dict.
The function should delete all dictionaries which value of density is lower than `5.500`

Expected output would be:

```
[{'name': 'Earth', 'Density': 5.513}]
```

Mine is:

```
[{'name': 'Earth', 'Density': 5.513}, 
 {'name': 'Venus', 'Density': 5.204}]`
```

My code:

```
base = [
    {"name": "Mars", "Density": 5.427},
    {"name": "Earth", "Density": 5.513},
    {"name": "Venus", "Density": 5.204},
]
density = float(input("density? "))

def deletePlanet(density, base):
    for index in range(0, len(base)):
        while base[index]["Density"] < density:
            del base[index]
            return base

print(deletePlanet(density, base))
```

Comment: Move the `return` outside the loop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove dictionary from list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235618/remove-dictionary-from-list) also [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: Also consider changing your list of dicts to a single dict of the form `name: density`. This way it is much easier to remove your wanted items

Answer (score 4):

Only return **after** the loop:

```
def deletePlanet(density, base):
    for index in range(0, len(base)):
        if base[index]["Density"] < density:  # why while?
            del base[index]
    return base
```

This is however bound to fail, as by the time you reach some of the indexes in your loop, they may no longer exist.

But generally you should never repeatedly remove from a list. Build it from scratch for better time complexity:

```
def deletePlanet(density, base):
    return [d for d in base if d["Density"] >= density]
```

If you want to mutate the existing list object, use slice assignment:

```
def deletePlanet(density, base):
    base[:] = [d for d in base if d["Density"] >= density]
    # return base
```

Comment: IndexError: list index out of range. It dont work( im talking about the first method you mention)

Comment: It works only for density from 0 to 5.427. What If i want it to be over this?

Comment: @randomobject123 then don't iterate over a list while removing elements from it and use one of the many other ways offered here and in the links above

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using

```
if base[index] < density:
```

instead of

```
while base[index] < density:
```

Comment: You all guys just deleting items while iterating them?

Answer (score 0):

hy randomobject123! I hope you are doing good. Kindly try this I hope this code will solve your problem.

**Code**

```
base = [
    {"name": "Mars", "Density": 5.427},
    {"name": "Earth", "Density": 5.513},
    {"name": "Venus", "Density": 5.204},
]
density = 5.500

def deletePlanet(density, base):
    return [i for i in base if i["Density"] >= density]
    
        

print(deletePlanet(density, base))
```

**Results**

```
[{'name': 'Earth', 'Density': 5.513}]
```

Comment: Don't use list-comprehensions for side effects. Also change `density` to `6` and see what happens

Comment: I don't think there is some issue while using so! If their is kinldy mention.

Comment: I don't think there is some issue while using so! If their is kinldy mention.

Comment: You managed to *not* get rid of the quadratic repeated removal *and* add a spurious in-memory list. This is just bad code.

Comment: [Is it Pythonic to use list comprehensions for just side effects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects)

Comment: Better, but now it's just a copy of another answer =)

Comment: @schwobaseggl you mean [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1235631/6045800)? ;)