# Delete object from dictionary

Tags: python

I have the following dictionary and I was wondering if there was a way to delete objects based off a key value when they are within a list. For instance,

```
 {'Root': [{'ID': '1', 'version': '3'},{'ID': '2', 'version': '4'},{'ID': '3', 'version': '3'}]}
```

Is there a way to delete everything in the list that has version == 3 ?
This post seems to be almost at the answer, but I have that additional "Root" layer:
[Remove dictionary from list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235618/remove-dictionary-from-list)
Thanks for any help!

Comment: That post *is* the answer. If you don't understand how to apply that answer to an element of a dictionary, then slow down and find a good Python tutorial to pick up the basics. That sort of elementary data structure manipulation is absolutely *necessary* to do anything of substance, not just in Python, but in any programming language.

Comment: Just grab the list in Root and apply the filtering from the other answer to it. Then either reassign it to the Root key or just create a new outer dict with a root key.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
new_dict['root'] = [element for element in old_dict['root'] if element['version'] !='3' ]
```

Comment: I think you mean `'3'` instead of `3`.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is start iterating over the list from : `for element in my_dict['Root']:` and then get that element i.e, the dictionary, and then fetch the value of that dictionary 's version.

```
my_dict={'Root': [{'ID': '1', 'version': '3'},{'ID': '2', 'version': '4'},{'ID': '3', 'version': '3'}]}
new_dict={}
for element in my_dict['Root']:
    if element['version']!="3":
        new_dict.update({"Root":[element]})
print(new_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will only print the items with version 4:-

```py
a_dict= {"Root": [{"ID": 1, "version": 3},{"ID": 2, "version": 4},{"ID": 3, "version": 3}]}
new_dict = {}

for item in a_dict['Root']:
   if item['version'] != 3:
      print(item)
      new_dict.update({'Root':[item]})

print(new_dict)
```

It will only print versions which are not 3.