# How to remove certain dictionaries from list?

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I have a list with dictionaries:

```
list_with_dicts = [{"nbr": 1, "id": 11}, {"nbr": 2, "id": 13}, {"nbr": 3, "id": 15}, ...]
```

I have a list that contains all the id:s I want to remove from the list with dictionaries:

```
ids = [11, 15, ...]
```

How can I do this effectively? I saw this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235618/remove-dictionary-from-list), however it does not cover if I need to iterate through the `ids` list.

Comment: Do you understand the code in that answer? Do you understand, in particular, how it is testing the id values? Can you think of a way to rewrite the `id` test to check whether the `id` is `in` your `ids` list (hint, hint)?

Comment: Sort of @KarlKnechtel. But my issue is that I need to iterate the ```ids``` list at the same time I'm iterating through the ```list_with_dicts```. No idea how to do that.

Comment: You don't iterate over the ids, you check whether the "id" is in the ids using `d["id"] in ids`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove dictionary from list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235618/remove-dictionary-from-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to iterate over the `ids` list, at least not explicitly. Iterate over the dictionaries list and check if the `id` value is in the `ids` list using `in`. If you itreate over a copy of the list you can use `remove(dict)` to remove the dictionary from the list

```
list_with_dicts = [{"nbr": 1, "id": 11}, {"nbr": 3, "id": 15}, {"nbr": 2, "id": 13}]
ids = [11, 15]

for d in list_with_dicts[:]:
    if d['id'] in ids:
        list_with_dicts.remove(d)

print(list_with_dicts) # [{'nbr': 2, 'id': 13}]
```

If you want to preserve the original list you can build a new one using list comprehensions

```
new_list_with_dicts = [d for d in list_with_dicts if d['id'] not in ids]
```